# Fill NSMutableArray from another NsMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I have two classes `indexViewController` and `flashCardQuestionViewController`.

In the `indexViewController` i have table filled with an array.

Now i am getting some data from the database:

```
-(void)getMultipleChoiceAnswer
{   
    if(optionid!=nil)
        [optionid removeAllObjects];
    else
        optionid = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if(optionText!=nil)
        [optionText removeAllObjects];
    else
        optionText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    clsDatabase *clsDatabaseObject = [[clsDatabase alloc] init];
    sqlite3_stmt *dataRows = [clsDatabaseObject getDataset:"select optionID,OptionText from flashCardMultipleAnswer where questionId=1"];
    while(sqlite3_step(dataRows) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        [optionid addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sqlite3_column_int(dataRows,0)]];
        [optionText addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(dataRows,1)]]; 
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(dataRows);
    [clsDatabaseObject release];
}
```

and I am calling this method in the `viewDidLoad` method of the `indexViewController`.

Now I have another `NSMutableArray` in the `flashCardQuestionViewController` named `listNoOfOptionsInQuestion`.

I want to fill `listNoOfOptionsInQuestion` with objects from `optionText` array in  `indexViewController`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to copy arrays: you can either use -[NSArray copy] to get an immutable copy, or -[NSArray mutableCopy] for a mutable copy. Don't forget that copy adds a reference so you'll need a release or autorelease somewhere (if you're not using GC that is).

Alternatively, you can use -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:].

Given your example, it looks like you want to do something like this at the end:

```
[flashCardQuestionViewController setListNoOfOptionsInQuestion:optionText];
```

And then in FlashCardQuestionViewController, you want something like:

```
- (void)setListNoOfOptionsInQuestion:(NSArray *)options
{
  if (options != listNoOfOptionsInQuestion) {
    [listNoOfOptionsInQuestion release];
    listNoOfOptionsInQuestion = [options mutableCopy];
  }
}
```

Comment: this does not work.i have both NSMUtableArray in Both Classes

Comment: You’ll need to be a bit more specific about what does not work. Post some code maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Rahul,

Do you really need to have a completely different copy of the MutableArray in each object. Would it be possible to have both objects point to the same array? For instance:

```
ClassOne  *one = [[ClassOne alloc] init];
ClassTwo  *two = [[ClassTwo alloc] init];

//   build mutable array mArray
//   ...

one.objectArray = mArray;
two.objectArray = mArray;
```

Or do you need to make changes to the two arrays in different ways? The try this (as suggested by Chris above) :

```
ClassOne  *one = [[ClassOne alloc] init];
ClassTwo  *two = [[ClassTwo alloc] init];

//   build mutable array mArray
//   ...

one.objectArray = mArray;
two.objectArray = [mArray mutableCopy];
```

again, if this isn't what you need then you'll have to give us a more precise question or problem that we can identify.